# Shopware 6 Criteria Filter property options, PHP combine conditions

Tags: php, symfony, if-statement, shopware, shopware6

The goal is to make some options of one property to be available for some selected options of another property.

In Shopware 6 Subscriber Criteria Filter works like this:

```
if (in_array('c0d02d1738fd4293a489695787e06b5c', $currentPropertyOptions)) {
    $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(
        new MultiFilter(
            Multifilter::CONNECTION_OR,
            [
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName01'),
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName02'),
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName03'),

                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName1'),
                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName2'),
                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName3')
            ]
        )
    );
}
elseif (in_array('3f777000a2734deead391133cee3a6a9', $currentPropertyOptions)) {
    $criteria = $event->getCriteria();
    $criteria->addFilter(
        new MultiFilter(
            Multifilter::CONNECTION_OR,
            [
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName01'),
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName02'),
                new EqualsFilter('product.properties.group.name', 'PropertyName03'),

                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName4'),
                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName5'),
                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName6'),
                new PrefixFilter('product.properties.name', 'OptionName7')
            ]
        )
    );
}
```

Can someone advice on how to implement cross-filtering/ combine conditions in this case? I mean, to include options for both Properties (if both conditions are true). Now only one result is available, if both options are checked in a storefront filter. Also we should have around 15 conditions.

P.S. We are going to make options-to-options admin assignable association via administration custom module using custom entity.

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, this is now the third question regarding essentially the same challenge. Just saying... maybe a little more research would be appropriate.

So, you're asking how to combine two filters, given two conditions are met? The array `$currentPropertyOptions` may include the two ids at the same time. Why are you using `elseif` then? Just have another `if` expression. Since both expressions may be true, you could add multiple filters to the same criteria. On the base level of the criteria all conditions have to be met. So, really, all you'd have to do is change `elseif` to `if` and it should do exactly what you want it do.

Comment: When I change elseif to if and tick 2 mentioned in conditions properties the page becomes not responding and eventually reaches 504 Gateway Timeout

Comment: It is a Timeout. There are no errors in server log. 

But I was able to make it finish filtering. But it gives only results for the 1st IF. Options from the 2nd IF are not added to criteria.